# Save stream from video grabber/capture device (2821)

Tags: video, streaming

Recently I bought a cheap video grabber device (2821 device). It did not ship with any software. This is a similar product:

[image: Photo of a video grabber device]

I am looking for a simple application which allows me to save the incoming video stream to an MPEG2/AVI.

I tried with VLC, but for some reason I do not understand, the audio is not in sync with the video (the audio is in sync during playback, however, when recording/saving the input, the audio is not in sync anymore). While I am still trying to fix that, I am also looking/asking for alternatives.

Any of you have some experiences with this?

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't used below stated software for this purpose I think that they will work for you. 
 
[GrabBee - AV](http://www.videohome.com.tw/eng/products-detail.php?p_id=72&level1_id=18) - user [A. Koziol](http://www.amazon.com/review/R13EG4HUZZRZBW/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B000O5RIWO&nodeID=172282&store=electronics) from amazon.com recommends this software.

[BS.Player PRO](http://www.bsplayer.com/bsplayer-english/products/bsplayer-pro.html) has support for capture and tuner devices (and Teletext support) and for
capturing video from capture device to hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with command-line, and you're on Windows, you can try [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html)'s "[dshow](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow)" option.

First, run this command to see what DirectShow devices are available and what they are called:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

You will see the names of available video capture devices listed under "DirectShow video devices" and audio devices listed under "DirectShow audio devices," in quotation marks.

Make a note of the name of your device (e.g. "Cheap Video Grabber") so you can use it in the next command.

If your video capture device only appears under "video devices", try this command:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Cheap Video Grabber" outputFile.mp4
```

If your video capture device appears under both "video devices" and "audio devices", you may need to specify that you want to capture both streams:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Cheap Video Grabber":audio="Cheap Audio Grabber" outputFile.mp4
```

If you prefer AVI instead of MP4, just change "outputFile.mp4" to "outputFile.avi". There are dozens of other [supported formats](http://ffmpeg.org/general.html#File-Formats).

If you're still having issues with audio/video sync, ffmpeg has an option to let you introduce a [delay into the audio or video stream](https://superuser.com/questions/982342/in-ffmpeg-how-to-delay-only-the-audio-of-a-mp4-video-without-converting-the-au) to get them back in sync.